# How can I delete array elements inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach loop and I would like to completely remove the array elements that satisfy the criteria, and change the keys to stay sequential 1,2,3,4.

I have:

```
$thearray = array(20,1,15,12,3,6,93);
foreach($thearray as $key => $value){
    if($value < 10){
        unset($thearray[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($thearray);
```

But this keeps the keys as they were before. I want to make them 1,2,3,4, how can this be achieved?

Comment: This gives me: Array ( [0] => 20 [2] => 15 [3] => 12 [6] => 93 ) But I want the key to be 0,1,2,3 not 0,2,3,6...

Comment: Have you even tried to look that up in te php documentation, section Array functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reset the array indices with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$thearray = array_values( $thearray);
print_r($thearray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `array_filter` to `remove the array elements that satisfy the criteria`

```
 $thisarray = array_filter($thearray,function($v){ return $v > 10 ;});
```

Then use `array_values` change the keys to stay 0, 1,2,3,4 .... as required

```
  $thisarray = array_values($thisarray);
```

Comment: `array_filter` will keep the old indices.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ??

Comment: Closures are supported from php version 5.3.0.

Comment: I think I do not have that sorry.  I have now solved it with your help guys using array_values.  problem solved.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Build up a new array and then assign that to your original array after:

```
$thearray=array(20,1,15,12,3,6,93);
$newarray=array();
foreach($thearray as $key=>$value){
  if($value>=10){
    $newarray[]=$value
  }
}
$thearray=$newarray;
print_r($thearray);
```